# TFS 2013 query bugs under PBI count

Tags: tfs

I have a PBI to collect all show-stopper bugs and display them on the SCRUM board.
(actually, I have one parent PBI like that, and 3 child PBIs - one per each team).

I want to display the bugs count in the home page of my project, either as 3 different squares, or as a pivot table by PBI.

For example, I created "work items with direct links" query, which returns the PBI and 2 bugs under it. but when i pin this query to my home page, it displays the count "3" (1 PBI + 2 bugs). I want to display only the children count.

How can I do it?

Thanks,
Annat.

Comment: Can you show the code you've written so far? It's necessary to help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinning a query to the home page is just going to show the number of Work Items returned by the query regardless of hierarchy.

Work Item Charting (for your pivot table) only works with flat queries (rather than direct link or tree queries) so that isn't going to work in this scenario.

Could you use another way to indicate the showstoppers such as AreaPath or Tags and that way you could return the information in a flat query?

I prefer not to have nested PBIs on the backlog anyway as it means the child items can be prioritised independently.

Comment: Thanks. I found another field to tag these items. :-)